# Is circuit breaker pattern applicable for asynchronous requests also?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I am new to `microservice` architecture. I found lots of examples to implement circuit breakers in `synchronous` requests.

But do we need `circuit breakers` in `asynchronous` request flows also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Circuit Breaker Pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/reliability/circuit-breaker.html) is mostly applicable for synchronous service communication. It is meant to avoid that a service is becoming overwhelmed with requests, and that the clients start to retry the requests so that the situation gets even worse.

In an asynchronous, event-driven architecture, services put events on a broker, and consumers reads events **in its own pace** - so the producer and the consumer is *decoupled* so it does not have the same problem as with synchronous communication between services.

Answer (score 0):

Though circuit breaker is mainly applicable for synchronous applications, however, this can also be applied to asynchronous communications. This could be achieved by putting all requests on a queue, which one application consumes at its speed - a useful technique to avoid overloading servers. In this case the circuit breaks when the queue fills up.